# Field trip to a home-based mobile phone factory

Tags: microcontroller, mobile

1. What are the components I need for assembling a hobby mobile phone?
2. How would I go about assembling such a hobby device?
3. Are there laws governing assembly/use of such hobby devices?

Comment: As it stands this is far too broad.  You might like to narrow your question to something specific and answerable.

Comment: There are people that dedicate their entire careers to mobile phones.

Comment: Mobile phones are intentional radiators. Yes, there are generally laws about selling and using radio transmitters wherever there are governments to pass them.

Comment: @David, thanks but my question has been answered already.

Comment: @MattYoung yeah. Nokia and T-Mobile have very nice devices around the market so I was hoping there are interfaces I can use.  As it turned out in the answer below, I was right.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, thanks. So the rules differ per state/country?

Comment: Usually by country (with some coordination between countries), but I can't swear there are not internal differences somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it is likely that a country might restrict access to specific frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern mobile phones are complex, highly integrated devices. I described what would be needed in [a previous answer of mine to a similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/37244/8159). Take a look at the schematic of the [Neo FreeRunner](http://downloads.openmoko.org/developer/schematics/GTA02/Schematics_Freerunner-GTA02_A5-A7cumulative_public_RC0.pdf) phone to see what's involved.

For a very simple phone, you might be able to get away with a GSM module + some other electronics, as in the [DIY Cellphone](http://web.media.mit.edu/~mellis/cellphone/index.html?utm_medium=App.net).